# ANTLR generating c++ code inside c# file for a given grammar

Tags: c#, antlr

I'm trying to parse and execute a fairly simple Oracle SQL query in my C# application. For this, I decided to use ANTLR as a parser tool, since the grammar for the Oracle SQL language is already available for download from the [grammar list page](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list).

I've also picked up the latest version of ANTLR 3.4 and used the following command to generate C# source files to use in my application

```
java -cp antlr-3.4-complete.jar org.antlr.Tool OracleSQL.g
```

Small remark: the original grammar file had C as output language, so I've changed it to `CSharp2` (I've also tried `CSharp3`, but with no luck).

The problem with the code is that I get blocks of code like this one

```
if ((((( !(strcasecmp((const char*)LT(1)->getText(LT(1))->chars, "SUBPARTITION")) )&&
```

therefore the solution doesn't compile.

I've also tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923639/antlr-grammar-generating-invalid-c-sharp-code), but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Adrian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite often, ANTLR grammars contain embedded (target) code. C code, in your case. You can't simply change the `language=C;` into `language=CSharp2` (or another language): it will only cause ANTLR to generate a lexer and/or parser in C# with embedded C code. You'll have to rewrite all the embedded C code yourself.

For example, the following C targeted grammar:

```
grammar T;

options {
  language=C;
}

parse
 : Any* EOF {printf("done!\n");}
 ;

Any
 : .
 ;
```

should be rewritten (for C#) like this:

```
grammar T;

options {
  language=CSharp2; // or CSharp3
}

parse
 : Any* EOF {Console.WriteLine("done!");}
 ;

Any
 : .
 ;
```